# How to split one column to multiple?

Tags: r

May I ask how to split the column of a data frame into multiple columns, for example:

```
ID  value
10.A.S  1
11.A.S  2
12.A.S  3
10.A    4
11.A    5
12.A    6
```

I want to split the ID column based on the ".", and the expected result should be like:

```
ID  NO.    type treatment value
10.A.S  10  A      S        1
11.A.S  11  A      S        2
12.A.S  12  A      S        3
10.A    10  A               4
11.A    11  A               5
12.A    12  A               6
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `separate`.   The `sep` in `separate` takes by default regex.  According to `?separate`

> sep - If character, is interpreted as a regular expression. The default value is a regular expression that matches any sequence of non-alphanumeric values.

The `.` is a metacharacter to match any character.  So, we either escape (`\\.`) or place it in square brackets (`[.]`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
      separate(ID, into = c("NO.", "type", "treatment"), 
                 sep="\\.", remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE)
```